# limit question: $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty } \frac{n}{2^n}=0$

Tags: calculus, limits, alternative-proof

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac n{2^n}=0. $$

I know how to prove it by using the trick, $2^n=(1+1)^n=1+n+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}+\text{...}$

But how to prove it without using this?

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/197522/how-to-prove-that-lim-n-to-infty-n-xn-0-when-0x1  and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/173061/sequence-limit-lim-limits-n-rightarrow-inftyn-xn

Comment: @HhyperGroups I wrote an answer that does not uses basic facts about limits only.

Comment: @Amr welcome---!, SE a good place to manage these questions/answers, I just wanna see many related `maths`, though some of them I'm not able to understand completely and respond quickly. But we can review whenever the time seems ripe.

Comment: It is nice that you have 12 answers (up till now) to your question.

Comment: @Amr Thanks, so let me accept your answer, of course so many good answers, then I should take time to enjoy them_ :)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Let's do something different!!

Note that the sequence $\{\frac{n}{2^n}\}_{n\geq 1}$  is decreasing ( easy to prove) and bounded from below by $0$, thus $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{n}{2^n}$ exists. Call it $L$.

> $$L=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{n}{2^n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow
>  \infty}\frac{(2n)}{2^{(2n)}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\frac{n}{2^n})=[\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}][\lim_{n\rightarrow
> \infty}\frac{n}{2^n}]=(0)(L)=0$$

Comment: Nice idea used!

Comment: also, note that it's bounded below

Comment: @enthdegree sure. I will include this. ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 13):

Put

$$a_n:=\frac{\sqrt[n]n}2\implies a_n\xrightarrow [n\to\infty]{}\frac12\implies$$

If we take say $\,\epsilon=0.1\;$ then

$$\exists\,N_\epsilon\in\Bbb N\;\;s.t.\;\;n>N_\epsilon\implies \left|a_n-\frac12\right|<0.1\iff \frac25<a_n<\frac35\implies$$

$$\implies \left(\frac25\right)^n<a_n^n=\frac n{2^n}<\left(\frac35\right)^n$$

Now apply the squeeze theorem and get what you want

Comment: Hi I think you might like my answer as well !

Comment: Is there a proof of $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n}=1$ that doesn't in some form use (or instantly adapt to) the questioner's limit?  It is, after all, instantly equivalent by taking logs to $\lim \frac{\log n}{n}=0$ and a quick substitution gives the OP's result...

Comment: @Steven, look at my answer here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154163/limit-of-the-sequence-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-sqrtnn/154188#154188

Comment: @DonAntonio Why didn't you use your very nice trick which I've learned from you of defining $a_n=\frac{n}{2^n}$ then, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{1}{2} < 1$ so by ratio test the series converges, i.e $a_n \rightarrow 0$

Comment: @harlem This was almost 5 years ago...yet there is *another* answer by me in then ext answers...maybe there.

Answer (score 10):

Let's be original. Let
$$
\frac 1{1-x} = \sum_{k \ge 0} x^k,
$$
which means the derivative of this series is also convergent with the same radius of convergence (namely, $1$) by Taylor's theorem : 
$$
x \left( \frac 1{(1-x)^2} \right) = x \left( \sum_{k \ge 0} k x^{k-1} \right) = \sum_{k \ge 0} k x^k.
$$
Letting $x = 1/2$, we see that the series
$$
\sum_{k \ge 0} \frac{k}{2^k}
$$
is convergent, hence $\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{k}{2^k} = 0$.

Hope that helps,

Comment: :nice approach .excellent $\large{+1}$

Comment: Yes. I had that in mind, too. But isn't it not sufficient to check $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} |a_{n+1} / a_n| = \frac 12$. That means $\sum_n a_n$ converges.

Comment: @André : Of course, you can prove that the series converges in many different ways. You used D'Alembert's criterion, I used the fact that the geometric series converges (which can be proved by just computing the limit of partial sums for instance) and then Taylor's theorem. It's as you wish

Answer (score 8):

Here is a useful result

> If $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=a $ and $|a|<1$, then $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = 0.$

Comment: It is nice to have different approaches to the solution.

Comment: I agree ${}{}{}$

Comment: @Amr : This question is old, very old.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva You mean the question that was asked by the OP ?

Comment: @Amr : I mean that this question (and its variations) have been asked many times on this website.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva I know and I often ignored these questions

Comment: @Amr : I often don't, because the reason I'm on this website is to help people, and if you don't help people at the beginning of their math journey then you certainly won't do it at the end.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the argument you did not want to see, in different language.

A set of $n$ elements has $2^n$ subsets.  If $n\ge 2$, then it has $\binom{n}{2}$ two-element subsets.

It follows that for $n\ge 2$ we have
$$2^n\ge \binom{n}{2}=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}.$$

Thus for $n\ge 2$ we have
$$0\le \frac{n}{2^n}\le \frac{2}{n-1}.$$

Comment: +1 Ah This is one is nice as well. I like combinatorial arguments

Comment: The question is easy , but its getting elegant answers which is a good thing for people who know the answer already.

Answer (score 5):

For $n$ large, we have $2^n\ge n^2$. This can be easily proved by induction for $n\ge 4$. I would like to say then that $$ \frac n{2^n}=\frac n{2^{\sqrt n}}\frac1{2^{n-\sqrt n}}, $$ and the first fraction is bounded above by $1$, while the second approaches $0$.

Now, since we used induction, we cannot quite do this as $\sqrt n$ is not an integer. So we adjust, letting $t_n=\lfloor \sqrt n\rfloor$, and $s_n=t_n^2$, then 
 $$ \frac n{2^n}=\frac{s_n}{2^{t_n}}\frac{n/s_n}{2^{n-t_n}}, $$
and the rest is clear, because $n/s_n<2$ and $n-t_n \to\infty$.

---

Just for fun, my favorite proof of $2^n\ge n^2$ for $n\ge4$, using the binomial theorem (which you have said you prefer to avoid): For $n=4$ we have equality, and if $n>4$ then $n-2>2$, so
$$2^n=(1+1)^n> n+\binom n2+\binom n{n-2}=n^2. $$

(Note that similar arguments give that for any fixed $k$, we have $2^n>n^k$ for $n$ large enough.)

Comment: Hi I also gave another answer which avoids inequalities

Answer (score 5):

$2^n \geq n^2,\,n \geq 2$. Hence, $0 \leq \frac{n}{2^n} \leq \frac{n}{n^2} = \frac{1}{n}$. Apply the Cheeseburger (Sandwich, Squeeze) theorem.

Comment: I think the most common name for that theorem around here is "Squeeze Theorem" . In my university though we used  to call it "the Sandwich theorem"

Comment: @DonAntonio Believe it or not, in France this is often called "[théorème des gendarmes](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Théorème_des_gendarmes)", which can approximately be translated by  "cops theorem".

Answer (score 3):

As $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac n{2^n}$ is of the form $\frac\infty\infty$

we can apply [L'Hospital's Rule](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LHospitalsRule.html) to get $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac n{2^n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{2^n\ln 2}=0$$

Comment: ah, fine, a little advanced for this section of the text. So I haven't thought that.

Comment: Hi I gave an answer which avoids l'Hospital's rule

Comment: Please disclose the mistake here

Comment: Even though it is mentioned nowwhere, but I always have the feeling that $n$ stands for a discrete variable e.g. $n\in \mathbb{N}$. For a discrete variable differentiating doesn't makes sense so maybe you could add some details when this works or what happens when it doesn't work.

Comment: @DominicMichaelis, why do you assume something not mentioned in the question? Why are you restricting the values of $n$ when the problem  is valid  for any real $n>0$

Comment: In his trick he used that $n \in \mathbb{N}$ didn't he ?

Comment: @DominicMichaelis, if you are talking about the restriction of http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Binomial_Theorem/General_Binomial_Theorem, this does not imply that $n$ has to be natural number, also observe his comment in this answer

Comment: But when $n\not\in \mathbb N$, some other answers like induction, or that of OL, or the combinatorial argument, cannot work. Maybe there is a need to justify this?

Comment: @DominicMichaelis I think that, on a discrete space, there is a measure(I have doubt about this, as, if the space is not finite, it is not compact.) hence we can differentiate that measure, right? Per chance I am talking above my head. :P

Answer (score 3):

By AM/GM:
$$\frac{2^{n}-1}{n}=\frac{2^0+2^1+\ldots +2^{n-1}}{n}\geq \left(2^{0+1+\ldots+(n-1)}\right)^{\frac1n}=2^{\frac{n-1}{2}}$$
Therefore,
$$0<\frac{n}{2^n}<\frac{n}{2^n-1}\leq 2^{-\frac{n-1}{2}}\rightarrow 0\quad\text{as}\quad
n\rightarrow\infty.$$

Answer (score 3):

One more answer with another approach I've used several times in this site and I'm surprised nobody's yet used. Put

$$a_n:=\frac n{2^n}\implies \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{n+1}{2^{n+1}}\frac{2^n}n=\frac12\frac{n+1}n\xrightarrow [n\to\infty]{}\frac12$$

and thus the quotient (D'Alembert's) test gives us that the positive series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac n{2^n}\;\;\text{converges}\implies \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac n{2^n}=0$$

Comment: Essentially, isn't the same answer given by Mhenni Benghorbal?

Comment: Without mentioning series there, yes...but also pretty similar to some others, among them my first answer itself.

Answer (score 2):

Using exponential and logarithm: $$\frac{n}{2^n}= \exp \underset{\to - \infty}{\underbrace{\left( n \left( \underset{\to 0}{\underbrace{\frac{\ln(n)}{n}}} - \ln(2) \right) \right)}} \underset{n \to + \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0$$

Comment: Excuse me, how could you show that the inner expression $\lim_{n\to\infty}n(\frac{\ln(n)}{n}-\ln2)=-\infty$? Is there a way of doing so without using the original statement? If so, would you like to show it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It follows from the classical limit $\frac{\ln(n)}{n} \to 0$, as I mentionned. Do you want more details about this limit?

Comment: Yes, if you mind not. Thanks.

Comment: More generally, you have $\lim\limits_{x \to + \infty} \frac{\ln(x)}{x}=0$; taking $x=e^y$, the previous limit is equivalent to $\lim\limits_{y \to + \infty} ye^{-y}=0$ or $\lim\limits_{y \to + \infty} \frac{e^y}{y}=+ \infty$. To conclude, it is sufficient to notice that $e^y \geq \frac{y^2}{2}$ for $y \geq 0$; for an elementary proof, show that $f(y)=e^y- \frac{y^2}{2}$ is non-negative on $[0,+ \infty)$ by computing $f'$ and $f''$.

Comment: So you have to show that $f'\ge 0$ to conclude that the minimal point occurs at $y=0$, right? And this is equivalent with showing that $g(y)=e^y-y$ is non-negative. Since $g$ is convex, the maximum principle implies that the extreme values occur at boundary points, hence its non-negativity. Is this argument right? Or is there some more elementary method? Thanks.

Comment: You can say that $f''$ is positive, so $f'$ is nondecreasing; because $f'(0)=1$, you deduce that $f'$ is positive hence $f$ is nondecreasing. Finally, $f(0)=1$ implies that $f \geq 0$.

Comment: OK, good; it is indeed an elementary way of solving this. Thanks for the clarification thus. :D

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$
a={\sqrt{2}}-1>0.
$$
Then, using Bernoulli's inequality we obtain
$$
0<\frac{n}{2^n}=\frac{n}{(\sqrt{2})^{2n}}=\frac{n}{(1+a)^{2n}}
=\frac{n}{\big((1+a)^{n}\big)^2}\le \frac{n}{(1+na)^2}\to 0,
$$
and hence $\frac{n}{2^n}\to 0$.